# How can I correctly plot a colorbar in a poster using baposter class?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, baposter

I'm preparing a poster using baposter class. I have one picture which requires a colorbar to be understood. The code of this tikz picture is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4cm,
height=3cm,
at={(0.756in,0.481in)},
scale only axis,
point meta min=-150,
point meta max=0,
axis on top,
xmin=-90.0879765395894,
xmax=90.0879765395894,
ymin=-0.500488758553275,
ymax=0.500488758553275,
yticklabel shift={.15cm},
xticklabel shift={.2cm},
xticklabels={,,},
y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.04,.5)},rotate=0,anchor=south},
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={Normalized frequency},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
colormap/jet,
colorbar,
colorbar style={
    yticklabel shift={.15cm}}
]
\addplot [forget plot] graphics [xmin=-90.0879765395894, xmax=90.0879765395894, ymin=-0.500488758553275, ymax=0.500488758553275] {TX-poster-1.png};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Although it works well in IEEEtran class, what I get is the following
[image]

Does anybody know what can I do to get the colorbar of the colormap jet correctly? It is too dark!

Thank you very much in advance!

Please, find here a minimal example (full document):

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.33]{baposter}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{palatino} 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} 
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{multicol} 

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}
{
headerborder=closed, 
colspacing=1em, 
bgColorOne=white, 
bgColorTwo=white, 
borderColor=ballblue, 
headerColorOne=ballblue, 
headerColorTwo=ballblue, 
headerFontColor=white, 
boxColorOne=white, 
textborder=roundedleft, 
eyecatcher=true, 
headerheight=0.15\textheight, 
headershape=roundedright, 
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, 
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, 
linewidth=2pt
}

\headerbox{Numerical Examples}{name=examples,column=1,span=2,below=min_norm,bottomaligned=problem}{
\end{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em, noitemsep]
        \item ST-PSD at TX (up) and RX (down)
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \input{TX-poster.tikz}
    \end{minipage}  
    \hspace{0.5em}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \input{RX-poster.tikz}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
}
\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide one (or two) full minimal document(s) which start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. In this case this is particularly important since, if I understand you correctly, the document class has an impact on the color bar.